# Search API EntityRepresentationModel not found

Tags: spring-data-rest

I am trying to create a customize search API.

```
@RepositoryRestResource( collectionResourceRel = "products", path = "products" )
public interface ProductFamilyRepository extends JpaRepository<ProductFamily, UUID> {

   @RestResource( path = "pages", rel = "pages" )
   ProductFamily findByPageId( @Param( "pageId" ) String pageId );
```

Execute
http://localhost:8080/products/search/pages?pageId=p33

```
org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException: EntityRepresentationModel not found!
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.lambda$toModel$2(RepositorySearchController.java:219)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:401)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.toModel(RepositorySearchController.java:219)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearch(RepositorySearchController.java:185)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the return type. It have to be `List<ProductFamily>`